# Show all admin menus in a table

Tags: admin, admin-menu

I Made a menu to remove admin menus for people that are not allowed to see it so they don't make changes to the site.

[image: Like this]

But I can't get submenus to display only the main menu's

this is the code:

```
    <?php
class clean_Admin_Menu {

    public $toggleItemSlug = 'toggle_cleanadminmenu';
    public $toggleItemOrder = '300.1';
    public $hiddenItemsOptionName = 'toggle_cleanadminmenu_items';
    public $nonceName = 'toggle_cleanadminmenu_options';

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'admin_init' ) );

        //add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_styles' ) );
        //add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'enqueue_scripts' ) );

        //action to add menu pages on admin
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'addMenuPages' ) );

        //action for adding classes to admin menu items
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'adminMenuAction' ) );

    }



    //Checks if users has the correct email and removes menu's if the user id doens't match.
    public function toggle_menu_items() {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        //Getting emails from database(q_admin) 
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name= $wpdb->prefix.'q_admin';
        $DBP_results= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");
        $showMenu = false;
        //Check if emails match with the 2 databases
        foreach($DBP_results as $DBP_cols){
            if ((string)$current_user->data->user_email == (string)$DBP_cols->email){
                $showMenu = true;
                break;
            } else {
                $showMenu = false;
            }
        }

        if ( $showMenu ) {
            // logged in.
            ?>
            <script>
                (function($) {
                    var menusAreHidden = false;
                    $(function() {
                        $('.menu-top.clean-wp-admin-menu__valid-item').show();
                        $(document).trigger('wp-window-resized');
                        //When the toggle extra item clicked show/hide menu items
                        //Also trigger the wp-window-resized event for left menu
                        $('#toplevel_page_toggle_cleanadminmenu a').click(function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('.menu-top.clean-wp-admin-menu__valid-item').show();
                            $(document).trigger('wp-window-resized');
                        });
                        $('#adminmenu .wp-menu-open.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
                    });
                })(jQuery);
            </script>
            <?php
        } else {
            // not Logged in.

        }
    }





    //Redirect function when there are erros.
    public function admin_init() {
        if ( is_admin() ) {

            ob_start();

            add_action( 'admin_head', array( $this, 'toggle_menu_items' ) );

        }
    }



    /*
    // function to toggle the menu.
    public function toggle_menu_items2() {
        ?>
        <script>
        (function($) {
            var menusAreHidden = false;
            $(function() {
                  $('.menu-top.clean-wp-admin-menu__valid-item').show();
                    $(document).trigger('wp-window-resized');
                 //When the toggle extra item clicked show/hide menu items
                 //Also trigger the wp-window-resized event for left menu
                $('#toplevel_page_toggle_cleanadminmenu a').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                      $('.menu-top.clean-wp-admin-menu__valid-item').show();
                    $(document).trigger('wp-window-resized');
                });
                $('#adminmenu .wp-menu-open.hidden').removeClass('hidden');
            });
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    */






    //Add menu pages in admin
    public function addMenuPages()  {
        //toggle menu button
        /*
        add_menu_page(
            __('Toggle Menu', 'clean-admin-menu'),
            __('Toggle Menu', 'clean-admin-menu'),
            'manage_options',
            $this->toggleItemSlug,
            function () {  return false;  },
            "dashicons-hidden",
            $this->toggleItemOrder
        );
*/
        add_menu_page(
            __('Q Admin', 'clean-admin-menu'),
            __('Q Admin', 'clean-admin-menu'),
            'manage_options',
            'clean-admin-menu_options',
            array(
                $this,
                'settingspage'
            ),
            get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/q-favicon.png',
        );

        //action for adding css
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style.css', get_stylesheet_uri() );

        add_submenu_page ( 'clean-admin-menu_options', 'Q Menu', 'Admin List', 'read', 'theme-options.php', 'call_back_q');

        function call_back_q(){
            echo '<div class="wrap"><div id="icon-options-general" class="icon32"><br></div>
             <h2></h2></div><br>';
            include ('admin_list.php');
        }

    }




    // Add items to display the menus correctly
    public function adminMenuAction()  {

        global $_registered_pages, $_parent_pages, $menu, $admin_page_hooks, $submenu;
        global $self, $parent_file, $submenu_file, $plugin_page, $typenow, $_wp_real_parent_file;

        //list of items selected from settings page
        $selectedItems = $this->selectedItems();
        $menuItems     = wp_list_pluck($menu, 2);


        foreach ($menu as $k => $item) {
            // Reminder for parent menu items array
            // 0 = menu_title, 1 = capability, 2 = menu_slug, 3 = page_title, 4 = classes, 5 = hookname, 6 = icon_url

            $isSelected      = in_array($item[2], $selectedItems);
            $isCurrentItem   = false;
            $isCurrentParent = false;


            //check if item is parent of current item
            //if not both of them, it deserves to be hidden if it is selected
            if ($parent_file) {
                $isCurrentItem = ($item[2] == $parent_file);

                if (isset($_parent_pages[$parent_file])) {
                    $isCurrentParent = ($_parent_pages[$parent_file] === $item[2]);
                }
            }

            $isHidden = ($isSelected && false === ($isCurrentParent OR $isCurrentItem));

            if ($isHidden) {
                $menu[$k][4] = $item[4] . ' hidden clean-wp-admin-menu__valid-item';
            }
        }
    }

    public function settingsPage() {
        global $_registered_pages, $_parent_pages, $menu, $admin_page_hooks, $submenu;

        $this->saveSettings();
        $pluginName = 'clean-admin-menu';
        $selectedItems = $this->selectedItems();

        ?>
        <style>
            .wrap td, .wrap th { text-align: left; }
            .table-menulist{ background-color: #fff; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; }
            .table-menulist th { padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #DFDFDF; }
            .table-menulist td  { padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1px solid #DFDFDF; }
            .table-menulist tr:last-child td  { border-bottom: 0;}
            .table-menulist .awaiting-mod, .table-menulist .update-plugins {display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;box-sizing: border-box;margin: 1px 0 -1px 2px;padding: 0 5px;border-radius: 9px;color: #fff;font-size: 11px;line-height: 1.6;text-align: center;z-index: 26;}
        </style>
        <div class="content">
            <div id="main">
                <div class="wrap">
                    <h1><?php esc_html_e('Q Admin Menu', $pluginName); ?></h1>
                    <?php
                    echo (($_GET['saved']==1)?'<div class="updated"><p>' . __('Success! Admin menu cleaned successfully', 'clean-admin-menu') . '</p></div>':'');
                    ?>
                    <form action="<?php echo esc_attr(admin_url('admin.php?page=clean-admin-menu_options')); ?>" method="post">
                        <?php wp_nonce_field($this->nonceName, $this->nonceName, true, true); ?>
                        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_html_e('SAVE CHANGES', $pluginName); ?>"/>
                        <table class="table-menulist">
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th style="width:300px;">Menu Items</th>
                            </tr>
                            <?php

                            $separator = 0;
                            foreach ($menu as $key => $menuItem){
                                $isSeparator = strpos($menuItem[4], 'wp-menu-separator');
                                $isSelected  = in_array($menuItem[2], $selectedItems);

                                //if ($isSeparator !== false OR $menuItem[2] === 'toggle_cleanadminmenu') {
                                if ($isSeparator !== false) {
                                    $menuItem[0] = '――――――separator――――――';
                                    $separator++;
                                }

                                // Hiding the Separator before the "toggle menu" link
                                if($separator > 1) { $separator = 0; continue; }

                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="toggle_cleanadminmenu_items[]" value="<?php echo $menuItem[2]; ?>"
                                               id="toggle_cleanadminmenu_item_<?php echo $key; ?>"
                                            <?php echo ($isSelected) ? 'checked' : ''; ?>
                                            <?php //echo ($menuItem[2] === 'index.php') ? 'disabled' : ''; ?> />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <?php if ($isSelected){ ?>
                                            <span style="color:#CA4A1F;" class="dashicons-before dashicons-hidden"></span>
                                        <?php }else{?>
                                            <span style="color:#18dc0b;" class="dashicons-before dashicons-visibility"></span>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="toggle_cleanadminmenu_item_<?php echo $key; ?>">
                                            <strong <?php echo ($isSeparator !== false?'style="color:#B7B7B7;"':'')?>>
                                                <?php
                                                if ($menuItem[2] === 'clean-admin-menu_options')
                                                    echo '―― '.strtoupper($menuItem[0]).' ――<br><sub style="color:#616A74;">Alleen zichtbaar voor super admins</sub>';
                                                else
                                                    echo $menuItem[0];
                                                ?>
                                            </strong>
                                        </label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                    <hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }




    public function selectedItems() {
        $items = get_option($this->hiddenItemsOptionName);
        if (!$items) {
            $items = array();
            return $items;
        }
        return $items;
    }

    private function saveSettings() {
        global $menu;

        if (!isset($_POST[$this->nonceName])) {
            return false;
        }

        $verify = check_admin_referer($this->nonceName, $this->nonceName);

        //TODO if empty but has post delete items

        if (!isset($_POST['toggle_cleanadminmenu_items'])) {
            $itemsToSave = array();
            $savedSuccess = 0;
        } else {

            $menuItems = wp_list_pluck($menu, 2);
            $items = $_POST['toggle_cleanadminmenu_items'];

            //save and check to see if it exists
            $itemsToSave = array();

            if ($items) {
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    if (in_array($item, $menuItems)) {
                        $itemsToSave[] = $item;
                    }
                }
            }
            $savedSuccess = 1;
        }

        //update and set as autoloading
        update_option($this->hiddenItemsOptionName, $itemsToSave, true);

        // we'll redirect to same page when saved to see results.
        $adminPageUrl = admin_url('options-general.php?page=clean-admin-menu_options&saved='.$savedSuccess);
        wp_safe_redirect( $adminPageUrl ); exit;
    }
}

new clean_Admin_Menu();
?>
```

I don't know how to get it to work hope somebody is able to help me.

Comment: I don't think I can offer much here, but why not use WordPress's built-in menu builder and permissions? Non-admins are already prevented from seeing or modifying admin screens they don't have access to.

Comment: @phatskat because I want them to be able to make some edits but they should not be able to edit everything.